# Show last 24 hours from selected date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 columns in my table, one has the hours and the other one has the dates. However, I want to show the last 24 hours from today's date and selected hour. For instance, if I select 10:30 am as my random hour, I want to show the last 24 hours from 10:30 am and from today's date.

I believe my syntax is wrong, please help.

```
select 
    ID, MilitaryHours, DT 
from 
    myTable 
where 
    MilitaryHours >= 1030 and DT  >= DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
```

Here is my ddl

```
CREATE TABLE myTabl
(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MilitaryHours] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [DT] [datetime] NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Diary] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` DDL for `myTable` so it's clear which data types are involved.

Comment: i added.  i think i need to change the data type for the military hours

Comment: Does your DT datetime column contain the same time stored in the MilitaryHours column?

Comment: the DT has only the Date values.

Comment: Why use a `DATETIME` rather than a `DATE` to store a date? Why subtract 24 hours from a date/time to subtract one day from a date?

Comment: and the  DT datatype is DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the time with the date so you have a proper `DATETIME` column so you query against it. If the date and time was stored correctly this would be easy.

If you are going to store `DATE` and `TIME` values seperately then use the correct datatypes (i.e. not `VARCHAR/NVARCHAR`)

```
WITH FullDatetime AS 
(
    SELECT
        ID
        , DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', DT), 
            CAST(LEFT(MilitaryHours,2) + ':' + RIGHT(MilitaryHours,2) + ':' + '00' AS DATETIME)) AS FullDatetime

    FROM
        myTable
)

SELECT
    *

FROM
    FullDatetime

WHERE
    FullDatetime BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: i am getting incorrect syntax SELECT
        ID
        , DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', DT), 
            CAST(LEFT(MilitaryHours,2) + ':' + RIGHT(MilitaryHours,2) + ':' + 00 AS DATETIME) AS FullDatetime

    FROM
        myTable

Comment: it does not like this: AS fulldatetime

Comment: Likely missing a bracket at the end, before the AS.

Comment: yep, i fixed but got another one: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '00:00:' to data type int.

Comment: Yes, the 00 towards the end needs to be in quotes. I have updated the above SQL.

Comment: that worked, but where would i put the hour in the query? like give me the last 24 hours from 10:am or last 24 hours from 11:30 pm.  If i look at my initial query i had this where MilitaryHours >= 1000

Comment: You would adjust the `WHERE` clause to suit your requirements. For example, if you replaced `GETDATE()` with '20150217 10:00:00' this would give you the previous 24 hours upto 10:00 today.